# Why can't I use Java's getDeclaredMethod() in Processing?

Tags: java, reflection, processing

I want to create a simple method queue in Processing and I'm trying to do it with Java's native reflection. Why does `getDeclaredMethod()` not work in this sample? Is there a way to make it work? Regardless of the variations on it that I have tried, it always returns `NoSuchMethodException`...

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

void draw() {
  Testclass t = new Testclass();
  Class myClass = t.getClass();
  println("Class: " + myClass);

  // This doesn't work...
  Method m = myClass.getDeclaredMethod("doSomething");

  // This works just fine...
  println(myClass.getDeclaredMethods());

  exit();
}



// Some fake class...
class Testclass {
  Testclass() {
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    println("hi");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's returning a `NoSuchMethodException`. The error you're seeing is:

`Unhandled exception type NoSuchMethodException`

And you're seeing this because `getDeclaredMethod()` **can** throw a `NoSuchMethodException`, so you have to put it in a try-catch block.

In other words, you aren't getting a `NoSuchMethodException`. You're getting a compiler error because you aren't wrapping the `getDeclaredMethod()` in a try-catch block. To fix it, simply add a try-catch block around your call to `getDeclaredMethod()`.

```
  try{
    Method m = myClass.getDeclaredMethod("doSomething");
    println("doSomething: " + m);
  }
  catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```